# Passing Data in Swift Between View Controllers in Same File

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

Why can't I pass data from one view controller class to another view controller class when they are in the same .swift file?

I've done both of the tutorials linked bellow in an effort to understand passing data, and both have you make another .swift file for you second view controller. When I followed them exactly it works. When I do everything the same but just put the `class SecondViewController` in the same .swift file as the `class FirstViewController` it doesn't work. Why?

I'm building an application with three view controllers and I'd rather just keep all the code in one file if I can. Is this why it's not working or is it just bad form?

Tutorials:

[How to Pass Data from View Controller (Swift : Xcode) on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw)

[Segue Between Swift View Controllers on CodingExplorer](http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/)

This works:

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var TextField: UITextField!    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestViewController: ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as ViewTwo        
        DestViewController.LabelText = TextField.text        
    }
}

//  ViewTwo.swift
import UIKit
    class ViewTwo: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!    
    var LabelText = String()    
    override func viewDidLoad() {        
        Label.text = LabelText       
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var TextField: UITextField!    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestViewController: ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as ViewTwo        
        DestViewController.LabelText = TextField.text        
    }
}

class ViewTwo: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!    
    var LabelText = String()    
    override func viewDidLoad() {        
        Label.text = LabelText       
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste some code?

Comment: Why are you doing all this in same `.swift` file.  I think its not good practice. so use different `.swift` file for different `viewController`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working fine for me.

1. Have you set the classes for your views properly? The view with your textField (and probably a button to `ViewTwo`) should be set to `ViewController` and your second view with the label should be set to `ViewTwo`.
2. Check the connections between your label/textField. Are they properly connected to your class?
3. This is the code I used, which should be exactly the same:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var TextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewTwo
        DestViewController.LabelText = TextField.text
    }
}

class ViewTwo: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!

    var LabelText = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        Label.text = LabelText
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I must have been doing something wrong with that.

Turns out that the issue with my applying this stuff to my program was that I was trying to pass an array to a string. Passed it to an array and now it's working just fine.