# How to share a variable between subclasses in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, inheritance

I have a super class which has a boolean variable and I would like to share it between the subclasses (pass it by reference)

```
Class parentClass: UIViewController {
    var sharedVariable: Bool = false
}

Class firstChild: parentClass {

    @IBAction func myButtonTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        sharedVariable = true
    }
}

Class secondChild: parentClass {
    print(sharedVariable)
}
```

But when I change sharedVariable in firstClass it wont change it for secondClass.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: The code shown here won't even compile, so no-one can verify your problem, nor is it clear what the problem is as the code here doesn't reproduce it (in particular as it will never call `myButtonTouched` even if it did compile, which it won't). I can only guess that you mean `sharedVariable` to be only one variable instead of each instance having a separate one, in which case you could put `static` in front of its declaration and access `parentClass.sharedVariable`.

Comment: You need show how you create instances of these classes and clearly explain how the properties are updated and how the value isn't as you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data in Swift Between View Controllers in Same File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575020/passing-data-in-swift-between-view-controllers-in-same-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a static variable, like this (I corrected the code and code style a bit):

```
class ParentClass: UIViewController {
    static var sharedVariable: Bool = false
}

class FirstChild: ParentClass {

    @IBAction func myButtonTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        ParentClass.sharedVariable = true
    }
}

class SecondChild: ParentClass {
    func test() {
        print(ParentClass.sharedVariable)
    }
}
```

Then, to test, you can do:

```
let secondChild = SecondChild()
secondChild.test() // prints false
let firstChild = FirstChild()
firstChild.myButtonTouched(firstChild)
secondChild.test() //prints true
```

Comment: would be nice if you explain why you downvoted since this obviously answers the question..

Comment: I didn't down voted your answer. Actually it is the answer to my question.Thanks

Comment: @Besat someone else did, I like to learn from my errors, but nevermind ;)

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted the answer, but I assume the down-vote was related to the fact that you're kinda promoting an anti-pattern. Static variables should not be used for passing data from one instance to another.

Comment: @Cristik I agree with you, but the answer is correct as far as the letter of the question goes and we don't know the context in which it was being asked. There are semi legitimate cases when you can use a singleton e.g. database connections, app delegates etc. Whoever down voted would have been better to leave a comment.